# MySQL: Syntaxerror when using Join?

Tags: mysql, join, syntax-error

Can you find anything wrong with this query?

```
        SELECT * FROM requests 
        WHERE id = '".$id."' 
        LEFT JOIN request_data ON (requests.id = request_data.request_id) 
        GROUP BY requests.id
```

Been workingon it for a while but can't seem to get it right!

The database looks like this:

```
 -requests
   -id
   -another column
   -and a third one

 -request_data
   -request_id
   -key
   -value
```

EDIT: Oh right, and the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN request_data ON (requests.id = request_data.request_id) GROUP BY ' at line 3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what this query is meant to be doing. Why have you got `WHERE id = '".$id."' ` and `GROUP BY requests.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` is in the wrong place.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM requests 
    LEFT JOIN request_data ON (requests.id = request_data.request_id) 
    WHERE id = '".$id."'
```

You probably don't need a `GROUP BY` either as the `WHERE` ensures there will only be one `id` returned unless in some way you are relying on the hidden columns functionality (which you shouldn't as [the results are undefined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)).